# new operator overloading in c++ example

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have the following code which I can't understand the status after one line in main.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned long size_t;

const int MAX_BUFFER=3;
int buf[MAX_BUFFER]={0}; //Initialize to 0
int location=0;

struct Scalar {
    int val;
    Scalar(int v) : val(v) { };

    void* operator new(size_t /*not used*/) {
        if (location == MAX_BUFFER) {
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        } else {
            int* ptr = &buf[location];
            if ( buf[location] == 0) {
                location++;
            } else {
                return ptr;
            }
        }
    }
    void operator delete(void* ptr) {
        size_t my_loc = (int*)ptr - buf;
        buf[my_loc] = location;
        location = my_loc;
    }
};

int main() {
    Scalar *s1 = new Scalar(11);
    cout << buf[0];
}
```

Why does the array `buf` in the end of this code contains the value 11 at the...?
I'm am not sure where the `val` input plays a role.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend typedefing your own `size_t`. Just use the one provided.

Comment: Are you sure about the `else {return ptr;}`? I think this is wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you only conditionally increment `location` after an allocation, and if you increment `location`, then the function doesn't execute a `return` statement which is undefined behavior.

Your deallocation strategy is completely broken unless objects are only deallocated in the exact opposite order of allocations.  Additionally, after the array element has been used for one allocation, it won't ever be used again due to the assignment in the deallocator.

As for the actual question: the first `Scalar` allocated is allocated at the same location as the buffer, so the first `Scalar` and `buf[0]` share the same memory.  As they're both composed of a single `int`, writes to one might be readable from the other.  And when you construct the `Scalar`, it assigns the value `11` to the shared memory.  I think doing this is undefined behavior, but I'm not certain.

Comment: i know that this is not the best way to work. i would like to understand how the value 11 gets into buf[0].

Comment: @user3286882: edited post, I had misread the question the first time

Answer (score 2):

The value 11 gets into the buffer thanks to

```
Scalar(int v) : val(v) { };
```

that takes the parameter and copies it into the member `val`.

If the class instance is allocated at the address of the buffer (because of the customized `operator::new (size_t)` implementation) then it's possible that its first member ends up in the first array element.

Note that this code is totally broken for several reasons already pointed out by Mooing Duck.